# Amazon MQ ActiveMQ heartbeat never sent to client stomp php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, activemq-classic, stomp, amazon-mq

### Summary

I am trying to set up heartbeats with my Consumer so it can detect a dropped connection - if the broker is rebooted for example so it may reconnect to the failover.

I tested the code with the Consumer/Dispatcher running locally and the queue running in AWS and everything worked fine. However, when moving the code to AWS the Consumer sets up heartbeats with the server/broker, but the heartbeat is either never sent by the server/broker or never received by the client/Consumer. As a result the `HeartbeatException` is thrown as soon as the requested server heartbeat interval has passed.

I based my code on the examples in the stomp-php-examples github

- Repo: https://github.com/stomp-php/stomp-php-examples
- Heartbeat example: https://github.com/stomp-php/stomp-php-examples/blob/support/version-4/src/heartbeats_server.php

My next best guess to as why this isn't working is something related to the queue config as I'm using the default config provided by AWS (*I think*). I have googled and searched all over about config settings for heartbeats but haven't got very far as this is a new topic. Any help would be appreciated!

### Setup

- Amazon MQ (ActiveMQ 5.15.14)
- [stomp-php](https://github.com/stomp-php/stomp-php) 5.0 (latest version as of today)

I'm happy to provide any more details of my setup.

### Code

Consumer (stripped down version)

```
abstract class AmqConsumerAbstract
{
    /** @var StatefulStomp */
    protected $consumer;

    const HEARTBEAT = 5000;

    public function listen(): void
    {
        $observer = new ServerAliveObserver();
        $this->client->getConnection()->getObservers()->addObserver($observer);
        $this->client->setHeartbeat(0, self::HEARTBEAT); // heartbeats setup here
        // Note: the heartbeat above is longer than the read-timeout below

        $this->client->getConnection()->setReadTimeout(2, 0);

        $this->client->connect();

        $this->consumer = new StatefulStomp($this->client);
        $this->consumer->subscribe(
            $this->getQueueName(),
            null,
            'client'
        );

        if (!$observer->isEnabled()) {
            // we never get here so I assume everything is working OK
            echo 'The Server is not supporting heartbeats.');
            exit(1);
        } else {
            echo sprintf('The Server should send us signals every %d ms.', $observer->getInterval() * 1000);
        }

        try {
            while (true) {
                $frame = $this->consumer->read(); // I assumed this line would read the heartbeat?

                // there is then some logic that deals with payload and does
                // $this->consumer->begin();
                // $this->consumer->ack($frame);
                // $this->consumer->commit();

                if ($observer->isDelayed()) {
                    $this->echoLog('ServerAliveObserver: Server has been delayed.');
                }
            }
        } catch (HeartbeatException $e) {
            echo 'AMQ (STOMP) Error, the server failed to send us heartbeats within the defined interval: ' . $e->getMessage()
            $this->reconnect();
        } catch (ConnectionException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            $this->reconnect();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'AMQ (STOMP) Queue error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

I have reproduced on a single-instance broker with version 5.15.14.

I have tried switching on [STOMP debugging for the broker](https://activemq.apache.org/stomp#debugging), but it appears the `uri` attribute under `<transportConnector>` is not allowed. The config will save but pulls out the `uri` attribute.

[`<transportConnector>` Elements and Their Attributes Permitted in Amazon MQ Configurations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/permitted-attributes.html#transportConnector.attributes)

[Working with Spring XML configuration files (xsd files)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/amazon-mq-broker-configuration-parameters.html)

Comment: @JustinBertram Thanks for your comment. Yes, I have just reproduced on a Single-instance broker with version 5.15.14.

Comment: @JustinBertram I have not been able to switch on debugging via `<transportConnector>`, I updated my question with the details.

Comment: When I asked you to reproduce this with *standalone* ActiveMQ 5.15.4 I meant *outside of the Amazon cloud*. For example, set up an instance of ActiveMQ 5.15.4 on your local machine and point your client to it and reproduce the issue. If you can reproduce it then you have full control of the configuration so you can enable whatever logging you need. If you can't reproduce it that means there's something going wrong with the Amazon MQ integration with ActiveMQ or perhaps in the Amazon cloud environment itself.

Comment: Thanks @JustinBertram I'd misunderstood. I'll try see if I can duplicate with the queue running locally too and see where that takes me. Thanks again for your comments!

Comment: Any update on this? Were you able to reproduce with standalone ActiveMQ 5.15.14? If so, did you capture any debug logging?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't get a chance to try yet, I spent a full week trying to get it working and for now my efforts are placed elsewhere but I will be sure to update here as soon as I attempt again. I don't know if you have any recommendations to getting a queue to run locally? Is there a docker image you'd recommend? Thanks again.

Comment: It should be pretty simple. Just [download ActiveMQ 5.15.4](http://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/download/), unzip it, and run `./bin/activemq console`. That will start the broker, and then you can run your STOMP client against it. The necessary destinations should get created automatically.